# swift transition between two views take very long time

Tags: swift, view, nsurlsession, transition, presentviewcontroller

## with window.rootViewController the transition between two views take about 1 min

I have   a connection to my server when the return is a success, I change my rootViewControler, but it take a very long time. if i jump the code for the connection the view appear immediately ?

```
    self.logingSpinner.startAnimating();

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://apps/appsAuth")!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var err: NSError?

    var bodyData="siren=\(entrepriseId.text)&email=\(email.text)&pwd=\(pwd.text)";

    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary


        if(err != nil) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
        else {

            if let parseJSON = json {
                println("data retour \(parseJSON)")

                var success = parseJSON["error"] as? Int
                println("Succes: \(success)")


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.logingSpinner.stopAnimating();
                    bt.enabled = true;
                    bt.alpha = 1;
                }

                // si une erreur symfony est retournée
                if(success==nil){ success = 3};

                switch success!{
                    case 0:
                        println("auth success");
                       var data =  userDefault.dictionaryForKey("userInfos")!
                        data["login"] = self.email.text;
                        data["siren"] = self.entrepriseId.text;
                        data["pwd"] = self.pwd.text;
                        data["isLogged"] = true;
                        data["hasCredential"] = true;

                        userDefault.setObject(data, forKey : "userInfos");
                        userDefault.synchronize();
//CHANGE root View Controller 
                        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let initViewController: UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewAcc") as accueilViewController
                        var window :UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
                        window.rootViewController = initViewController
                        window.makeKeyAndVisible()


                    case 1 :
                        println("auth failed")
                    default :
                        println("default");
                }


            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }



        }
    })

    task.resume()
```

I have tried with presentViewControler the transition is immediat, but my image inside the view disapear , only the  button are in place ?
thank in advance for help

Comment: nobody to help about this ? i'm stuck i don't know why with the NSURLSession the view appear  late, some procees must keep memory but in debugger i don't see a big memory consumption and the network is release normaly . i think it's internat to ios but why ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Resolved

Yes ! after a long night i have find why my view take too much time to appear after the wiewdidload was executed.

it's about thread and NSUrlSession, with NSUrlSession the callback is on the background thread , and like I handle rootview inside, the view is not handled on the main thread, it should be (apple recommandation on user interface)!!!!
to solve it, I simply return this code execution on the main thread. in my completionHandler i do it

```
var task = self.session.dataTaskWithRequest(self.request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                mycallback(resultat: "success")

            })
 })
```

mycallback function handle rootviewcontroller
work's great .....

Answer (score 1):

## NSURLSession responsable to slow down view transition

I have not find yet why !  but it's the guilty. it strange because the completion function go at the end. someone know if after the completion func, a process is ever running.
sorry for my very bad english :-(

```
 let initViewController: UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewAcc") as accueilViewController
                var window :UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
 window.rootViewController = initViewController
 window.makeKeyAndVisible()
 println("end")
```

in the console println("end") is execute, i see the println(viewdidload)   from my accueilviewcontroller viewDidAppear function, in the console , but the view appear after more than one minute.